# Python - n Prime

Tags: python, primes

I’m new to python and I’m trying to figure out how to make a function where you enter a number and it gives you the number prime.

Example: If I enter 6 it returns 13. Since 13 is the 6th prime.

Preferably no modules except ones in standard library, 
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How do I make it.. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
def nth_prime_number(n):
    # initial prime number list
    prime_list = [2]
    # first number to test if prime
    num = 3
    # keep generating primes until we get to the nth one
    while len(prime_list) < n:

        # check if num is divisible by any prime before it
        for p in prime_list:
            # if there is no remainder dividing the number
            # then the number is not a prime
            if num % p == 0:
                # break to stop testing more numbers, we know it's not a prime
                break

        # if it is a prime, then add it to the list
        # after a for loop, else runs if the "break" command has not been given
        else:
            # append to prime list
            prime_list.append(num)

        # same optimization you had, don't check even numbers
        num += 2

    # return the last prime number generated
    return prime_list[-1]

x = nth_prime_number(8)
print(x)
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158929

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ! 
I am also attach the screenshot of the output .

```
num=int(input("Enter Position : "))
r =1000
count=0
import sys
for a in range(2,sys.maxsize**10):
    k=0
    for i in range(2,a//2+1):
        if(a%i==0):
            k=k+1

    if(k<=0):
        count=count+1
    if(count==num):
        print("Prime Number at position " , num , " is " , a)  
        break
```

[image]

Comment: And if I want the prime number 1000, does your code work?

Comment: yes this was the mistake in my code because I am limit the range to 1000 & prime number at 1000th position is not possible . Now I am updating the code . 
Thanks @eyllanesc